# AngularJS - get length of array from a webApi call on first call only

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to display text 'showing X of Y Attractions' where X is the number currently showing and Y is the total number stored in the database.

I can get X easily by using `{{Attractions.length}}` - but I'm stuck on the best way to get Y?

Currently I am obtaining the data through a service call, which is just doing a `$http` get to a web api controller to get all of the data initially, which can then be filtered.

```
$scope.Attractions = dataService.getAllAttractions();
```

I would like to do something like:

```
$scope.totalAttractions = dataService.getAllAttractions().length;
```

So basically my question is what is the best way to get `totalAttractions` in this scenario?

Edit, my `getAllAttractions` dataservice function:

```
function getAllAttractions() {

        $http.get("/api/v1/attractions")
            .then(function (response) {
                // Success
                angular.copy(response.data, attractions);
            }, function () {
                // Failure
        });
        return attractions;
    }
```

Comment: If you initially load `$scope.Attractions = dataService.getAllAttractions();` your next line could be `$scope.totalAttractions = $scope.Attractions.length`

Comment: Thanks yes, sorry tried that but it breaks the page?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Apologies, just retried and now just get 0.

Comment: If you log $scope.Attractions immediately after setting does it display the array you expect?

Comment: Yes showing all the right data and `{{Attractions.length}}` is working. Would `totalAttractions` need to be a promise all callback from the $http call?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118525/discussion-between-rian-odwyer-and-paolo-b).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to return an undefined `attractions` with your `getAllAttractions()`.

`$http.get` service is asynchronous and returns a promise. You should return that promise instead of `attractions`.

In your current code, I've inserted log display on the console.

```
function getAllAttractions() {

        $http.get("/api/v1/attractions")
            .then(function (response) {
                // Success
                console.log("success");
                angular.copy(response.data, attractions);
            }, function () {
                // Failure
                console.log("fail");
        });
        console.log("returned value");
        return attractions;
    }
```

Assuming you call the webservice successfully, console would probably display:

```
returned value
success
```

That is because the success callback is executed **after** you return `attractions`.

You should do this instead:

**dataService**

```
function getAllAttractions() {

        return $http.get("/api/v1/attractions");
    }
```

**controller**

```
dataService.getAllAttractions()
.then(function (response) {
        // Success
        $scope.attractions = response.data;
        $scope.totalAttractions = $scope.attractions.length;
}, function () {
        // Failure
});
```

Comment: Thanks, it works - used `$scope.totalAttractions = $scope.Attractions.length`

Comment: i forgot to add the .length property